# Run Hydra (mpiexec) locally gives strange SSH error

Tags: linux, ssh, mpi, hydra

I am trying to run example code from this question: [MPI basic example doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870111/mpi-basic-example-doesnt-work) but when I do:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 mpi_test
```

I get this:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname wvxvw-laptop: Name or service not known
```

And then the program hangs until interrupted.

`wvxvw-laptop` is the "host name" of my laptop, which is just that, really, a laptopt...

All I want is to try to run the example code, not to set up a network cluster or anything like that.

What did I miss? I'm reading the wiki page http://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager but I can't understand what is the reason.

Sorry, I'm very new to this.

---

Some more verbose output:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -x wvxvw-laptop "/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy" \
--control-port wvxvw-laptop:54320 --debug --rmk user --launcher ssh \
--demux poll --pgid 0 --retries 10 --usize -2 --proxy-id 0
```

Formatted for readability. I'm not quite sure why is this even supposed to work (I've never used `ssh -x` not sure what it is supposed to do :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mpirun execute your program on all node registered on your mpi cluster. 
MPI use the computer name so you can edit your /etc/hosts to add an entry for wvxvw-laptop

Comment: Yup, that and I also had to start `sshd` service (may be important for future reference if you test it on local PC, chances are you aren't running it).